# Скрипт контроля воспроизведения аудио

Tags: javascript, аудио

Задача: воспроизводить и прекращать воспроизведение аудио в зависимости от видимости блока. То есть, если блок имеет стиль `display: block`, то воспроизведение начинается до тех пор, пока стиль блока не сменится на `display: none`.

Вот пример функции, которая сменяет блоки:

```
function next_qestion() {
    if(document.getElementById('qestion2').style.display == "block"){
        document.getElementById('qestion2').style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById('qestion3').style.display = "block";
    }
    if(document.getElementById('qestion1').style.display == "block"){
        document.getElementById('qestion1').style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById('qestion2').style.display = "block";
    }
```

````
<div id="qestion34" style="display:none;">
    <p>Задание 1.</p>
    <div id="container"><audio id="sound" src="rvpi/1.1.wav" preload="auto" controls></audio></div>
<div class="alert alert-secondary" role="alert">
    <p><span id="v_34"></span><br><br><br>
        <label style="border: 2px solid black; width: 350px; margin-bottom:20px"><input class=" visual" type="radio" id="z_1" name="audirovanie1" value="28" >Вот он, справа.</label style="border: 2px solid black; width: 350px; margin-bottom:20px"><br>
        <label style="border: 2px solid black; width: 350px; margin-bottom:20px"><input class=" visual" type="radio" id="z_1" name="audirovanie1" value="250">На автобусе №12.</label style="border: 2px solid black; width: 350px; margin-bottom:20px"><br>
        <label style="border: 2px solid black; width: 350px; margin-bottom:20px"><input class=" visual" type="radio" id="z_1" name="audirovanie1" value="43">Я не еду в центр.</label style="border: 2px solid black; width: 350px; margin-bottom:20px"><br>
    </p>
</div>
</div>
<div id="qestion35" style="display:none;">
    <p>Задание 2.</p>
    <div id="container"><audio id="sound" src="rvpi/2.1.wav" preload="auto" controls></audio></div>
<div class="alert alert-secondary" role="alert">
    <p><span id="v_35"></span><br><br><br>
        <label style="border: 2px solid black; width: 350px; margin-bottom:20px"><input class=" visual" type="radio" id="z_1" name="audirovanie2" value="28" >У меня на родине никогда не бывает снега.</label style="border: 2px solid black; width: 350px; margin-bottom:20px"><br>
        <label style="border: 2px solid black; width: 350px; margin-bottom:20px"><input class=" visual" type="radio" id="z_1" name="audirovanie2" value="250">Вчера весь день шёл снег.</label style="border: 2px solid black; width: 350px; margin-bottom:20px"><br>
        <label style="border: 2px solid black; width: 350px; margin-bottom:20px"><input class=" visual" type="radio" id="z_1" name="audirovanie2" value="43">Думаю, да.</label style="border: 2px solid black; width: 350px; margin-bottom:20px"><br>
    </p>
</div>
</div>```
````

Comment: Что за аудио?.. Как блоки меняете - так и аудио вопроизводите/стопайте

Comment: аудио из тега html <audio>

Comment: Можете привести пример как это можно сделать?

Comment: document.getElementById('audio').play(); Попробовал таким образом но почему-то не срабатывает

Comment: @user407430: а само условие то работает? ;-)

Comment: Скиньте код полностью. С аудио тегами и прочим

Comment: Добавил кусок кода с тегами

Comment: Ответ был найден, банальная ошибка синтаксиса. Всем спасибо за помощь